# Debian package build fails for evince, when using the "--disable-dbus" option

Tags: build, debian

I am trying to build Debian package `evince`, on Debian Buster, using the Debian build process:

```
apt-get source evince
```

and then

```
cd evince-3.30.2/
dpkg-buildpackage --build=binary --no-sign
```

The build process is successful when I build the package with `dbus` (default setting).

When I change the configuration and add `--disable-dbus`, the build process fails with following error:

```
ev-application.c: In function ‘ev_application_new’:
ev-application.c:106:42: error: ‘APPLICATION_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘G_APPLICATION_CLASS’?
                    "application-id", APPLICATION_NAME,
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                      G_APPLICATION_CLASS
ev-application.c:106:42: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
ev-application.c:109:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
^
```

Bellow is snippet from the `debian/rules` file that works:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
  dh_auto_configure -- \
    --libexecdir=/usr/lib/evince \
    --enable-djvu \
    --enable-dvi \
    --enable-ps \
    --enable-introspection \
    --enable-gtk-doc \
    --disable-libgnome-desktop \
    --disable-multimedia \
    --disable-nautilus \
    --disable-browser-plugin \
    --without-keyring
```

and here is the the one that does not (the only change is added `--disable-dbus`):

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
  dh_auto_configure -- \
    --libexecdir=/usr/lib/evince \
    --enable-djvu \
    --enable-dvi \
    --enable-ps \
    --enable-introspection \
    --enable-gtk-doc \
    --disable-dbus \
    --disable-libgnome-desktop \
    --disable-multimedia \
    --disable-nautilus \
    --disable-browser-plugin \
    --without-keyring
```

**What does the error mean, and how can I fix it ?**

**UPDATE 2021-09-01**

I have fixed the `APPLICATION_NAME` as suggested by @cody.

I have also removed one-line reference to dbus in `debian/evince.install`

But building with `--disable-dbus` now ends with another error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/evince-scan.o: in function `get_object_types':
./help/reference/shell/evince-scan.c:43: undefined reference to `ev_media_player_keys_get_type'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [Makefile:867: scan-build.stamp] Error 1
make[4]: *** [Makefile:506: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:591: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [Makefile:730: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:595: all] Error 2
dh_auto_build: make -j4 returned exit code 2
make: *** [debian/rules:11: build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [moving the `APPLICATION_NAME` definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68987133/4500798), a few more changes are required to build the package with `--disable-dbus`:

- in `help/reference/shell/evince.types`, the `ev_media_player_keys_get_type` line needs to be removed;
- in `debian/evince.install`, the components which aren’t built when D-Bus support is disabled need to be removed:

  - `usr/lib/evince/evinced`
  - `usr/lib/systemd/user/`
  - `usr/share/dbus-1`

I’ve encapsulated the complete set of changes in [`evince-3.30.2-3+deb10u1+400cat1-nmu.diff`](https://sk2.org/evince-3.30.2-3+deb10u1+400cat1-nmu.diff); to build the package:

```
apt source evince/buster
cd evince-3.30.2
patch -p1 < /path/to/evince-3.30.2-3+deb10u1+400cat1-nmu.diff
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

(installing the required build-dependencies as necessary). The last step can be replaced with `pdebuild` or any other build tool you have set up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug in that version of the evince source code. If you look at the [most recent version of ev-application.c](https://github.com/GNOME/evince/blob/master/shell/ev-application.c), you will note that `APPLICATION_NAME` is defined outside of the adjacent `#ifdef ENABLE_DBUS`:

```
#define APPLICATION_NAME             "org.gnome.Evince"
#ifdef ENABLE_DBUS
#define APPLICATION_DBUS_OBJECT_PATH "/org/gnome/evince/Evince"
#define APPLICATION_DBUS_INTERFACE   "org.gnome.evince.Application"
...
#endif
```

But if you then look at [the version in Debian Buster](https://sources.debian.org/src/evince/3.30.2-3+deb10u1/shell/ev-application.c/#L68), you will note that it is defined INSIDE that `#ifdef`:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DBUS
#define APPLICATION_NAME             "org.gnome.Evince"
#define APPLICATION_DBUS_OBJECT_PATH "/org/gnome/evince/Evince"
#define APPLICATION_DBUS_INTERFACE   "org.gnome.evince.Application"
...
#endif
```

So in the Debian version, if dbus is disabled, `APPLICATION_NAME` will not be defined. I believe all you would need to do is alter ev-application.c to move that definition of `APPLICATION_NAME` outside of the `#ifdef ENABLE_DBUS`, and it should compile.

This appears to have been [fixed](https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/evince/-/commit/674ab1de72145485f8ea2a715a6ff67a5c99548b) in the Debian repo as well.

Comment: thank you, but after fixing `APPLICATION_NAME`, I now get another  error: `help/reference/shell/evince-scan.c:43: undefined reference to `ev_media_player_keys_get_type'`. Please see my update. Did you actually try to build the package on your side?